# sql join to different columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that holds project manager and project director employee id's e.g

```
projectmanagerId
projectdirectorId
```

I need to link each of these columns to a employees table, however the problem is that the both the projectmanagerId column and ProjectDirectorId column need to link to either of 2 columns e.g

```
JEmployeeId
MEmployeeId
```

I thought about creating a junction table like so

```
ProjectManagerEmployeeJunction1
-------------------------------
projectmanagerId
JEmployeeId

ProjectManagerEmployeeJunction2
-------------------------------
projectmanagerId
MEmployeeId
```

and similar for the director. Is this the best way to do this.  Is there a better way.  It seems overkill to create 4 tables for this.

Comment: What's the difference in meaning between JEmployeeId and MEmployeeId?

Comment: @Bohemian They are project management systems.  The JEmployeeId is our old system and the MEmployeeId is our new system.  Both systems hold employee data with different employee id's.  I need to interface both as our contracts system needs to grab the data from the old and the new

Comment: please elaborate further, do you mean employees have two ids, JEmployeeId and MEmployeeId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it in a similar but slightly different way.

Rather than creating the table for ProjectManagers, and/or ProjectDirectors, create the table for all employees.

```
EmployeeIDJunction
------------------
externalID,
EmployeeUniqueID
```

An employee would then have two entries in the table.  One record where the externalID is the JEployeeID, and one record where the externalID is the MEmployeeID.  The EmployeeUnqiueID would then be *any* ID that you wanted to, that maps to your employee table.  You could, in theory, have as many as you liked, provided they were unqiue across the whole table (So as to avoid mapping one externalID to multiple employees).

```
  Data
INNER JOIN
  EmployeeIDJunction
    ON EmployeeIDJunction.externalID = Data.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN
  Employee
    ON Employee.ID = EmployeeIDJunction.EmployeeUniqueID
```

Just to re-itterate.  This all assumes that the different EmployeeIDs NEVER collide.  I can't EVER have an ID in one system that YOU ALSO have in a different system.

If that's possible you need to start doing things like prefixing the IDs, or using composite keys such as (SystemId, EmployeeID) pairs.  Either way, the concept above should still allow you to map multiple ID's to a single Employee record, without using OR's and so getting maximum benefit from INDEXes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `INNER JOIN` with `OR` clause, for example:

```
t1 inner join
t2 on projectmanagerId = JEmployeeID or projectmanagerID = MEmployeeID
```

Comment: It will work if the relationship if either but not both, but will perform badly - "or" logic doesn't use indexes

Answer (score 0):

- Get all your employee data into the new table
- Copy over everything that isn't in the new table
- Copy over the old employee ID too
- Update your project data records to replace old id with new id:

In pseudo sql:

```
update project_table set
employeeid = (select newid from newemp where old_id = employeeid)
where employeeid in (select old_id from newemp);
```

Now you only have one relationship to deal with.

Comment: One still has the situation where there are two external systems that *may* require changes to be propegated into the unified Employee entity.  There can be a variety of reasons such as these that one-time revision of ID's is not possible.  The alternative approach (that I often use) is to have a third LOCAL EmployeeID, mapping between the external systems and my local unified representation, and then use my local ID throughout all of my locally held data.  (ETL the external data to the local representations and then use the local ID as your single relationship.)

Comment: @Dems Given all that, your current approach is what I would do. Sounds fine to me.